# Pillow plugin adding support for the QOI image format

Tags: python, parsing, image

[Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) is a popular library for handling images in Python. My code adds support for the [QOI image format](https://qoiformat.org/) to Pillow.

Aside from loading and saving QOI images, my goal was to write a streaming decoder and encoder deriving from `PIL.ImageFile.PyDecoder` and `PIL.ImageFile.PyEncoder` respectively, which, as far as I know, has no documented example (all codecs in the PIL codebase set the `_pulls_fd`/`_pushes_fd` properties set to true, allowing to work with the full file at once). An overview of the decoding/encoding process can be found in the Pillow docs: [Writing Your Own File Codec in Python](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/writing-your-own-image-plugin.html#writing-your-own-file-codec-in-python).

The codec works and allows to load/save the reference `qoi` images provided on the QOI website.

Performance-wise, I'm satisfied with image decoding: decoding a PNG image is on average 3 to 5 times faster than the corresponding PNG. However, encoding is about 10 times slower than PNG, which is disappointing, given that the format is designed for fast encoding and decoding. Profiling shows that one of the main bottlenecks for encoding is the `_advance_pixel` method, however I can't think of any faster way to loop over the image's pixels.

Overall, I'm pretty satisfied with the code, but I'd be happy to have feedback and suggestions on how it could be improved overall.

You can find the code on [Github](https://github.com/Gaazoh/QoiImagePlugin/), or below:

```py
import struct
from functools import cache
from PIL import Image, ImageFile


QOI_MAGIC = b'qoif'
QOI_HEADER_RGB = 3
QOI_HEADER_RGBA = 4
QOI_HEADER_SRGB = 0
QOI_HEADER_LINEAR = 1
QOI_OP_RGB = 0xFE
QOI_OP_RGBA = 0xFF
QOI_OP_INDEX = 0x00
QOI_OP_DIFF = 0x40
QOI_OP_LUMA = 0x80
QOI_OP_RUN = 0xC0
QOI_OP_MASK = 0b11000000
QOI_EOF_MARKER = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'


def _accept(prefix):
    return prefix[:4] == QOI_MAGIC


@cache
def _pixel_hash(pixel):
    r, g, b, a = pixel
    return (r * 3 + g * 5 + b * 7 + a * 11) % 64


class QoiImageFile(ImageFile.ImageFile):
    """
    Image plugin for the QOI format (Quite OK Image format)
    """

    format = 'qoi'
    format_description = 'qoi format'

    def _open(self):
        self.fp.seek(4)
        self._size = struct.unpack('>II', self.fp.read(8))
        channels = struct.unpack('B', self.fp.read(1))[0]
        self.mode = 'RGB' if channels == QOI_HEADER_RGB else 'RGBA'
        self.info['colorspace'] = struct.unpack('B', self.fp.read(1))[0]

        self.tile = [('qoi', (0, 0) + self.size, 14, None)]


class QoiDecoder(ImageFile.PyDecoder):
    """
    Decoder for QOI image files
    """

    def __init__(self, mode, *args):
        super().__init__(mode, args)
        self.current_pixel = (0, 0, 0, 255)
        self.cache = [(0, 0, 0, 0) for _ in range(64)]
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def decode(self, buffer):
        i = 0
        while i + 5 < len(buffer):
            if buffer[i:i+8] == QOI_EOF_MARKER:
                return -1, 0
            tag = buffer[i]
            if tag == QOI_OP_RGBA:
                self.current_pixel = (buffer[i+1],
                                      buffer[i+2],
                                      buffer[i+3],
                                      buffer[i+4])
                i += 5

            elif tag == QOI_OP_RGB:
                self.current_pixel = (buffer[i+1],
                                      buffer[i+2],
                                      buffer[i+3],
                                      self.current_pixel[3])
                i += 4

            elif tag & QOI_OP_MASK == QOI_OP_INDEX:
                self.current_pixel = self.cache[tag & ~QOI_OP_MASK]
                i += 1

            elif tag & QOI_OP_MASK == QOI_OP_DIFF:
                dr = (tag >> 4 & 0b11) - 2
                dg = (tag >> 2 & 0b11) - 2
                db = (tag & 0b11) - 2
                self.current_pixel = ((self.current_pixel[0] + dr) % 256,
                                      (self.current_pixel[1] + dg) % 256,
                                      (self.current_pixel[2] + db) % 256,
                                      self.current_pixel[3])
                i += 1

            elif tag & QOI_OP_MASK == QOI_OP_LUMA:
                dg = (tag & ~QOI_OP_MASK) - 32
                diffs = buffer[i+1]
                dr = (diffs >> 4) - 8 + dg
                db = (diffs & 0b1111) - 8 + dg
                self.current_pixel = ((self.current_pixel[0] + dr) % 256,
                                      (self.current_pixel[1] + dg) % 256,
                                      (self.current_pixel[2] + db) % 256,
                                      self.current_pixel[3])
                i += 2
            elif tag & QOI_OP_MASK == QOI_OP_RUN:
                for _ in range((tag & ~QOI_OP_MASK) + 1):
                    self._set_pixel()
                i += 1
                continue

            self._set_pixel()
            self.cache[_pixel_hash(self.current_pixel)] = self.current_pixel
        return i, 0

    def cleanup(self):
        del self.cache
        del self.current_pixel
        del self.x
        del self.y

    def _set_pixel(self):
        if self.im.mode == 'RGBA':
            self.im.putpixel((self.x, self.y),
                             self.current_pixel)
        else:
            self.im.putpixel((self.x, self.y),
                             self.current_pixel[:3])
        self.x += 1
        if self.x >= self.im.size[0]:
            self.y += 1
            self.x = 0


class QoiEncoder(ImageFile.PyEncoder):
    """
    Encoder for QOI image files
    """

    def __init__(self, mode, *args):
        super().__init__(mode, args)
        self.previous_pixel = (0, 0, 0, 255)
        self.cache = [(0, 0, 0, 0) for _ in range(64)]
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.run = 0
        self.eof = False

    def encode(self, bufsize):
        buffer = bytearray(bufsize)
        i = 0
        while not self.eof and i + 6 < bufsize:
            pixel = self.im.getpixel((self.x, self.y))
            if len(pixel) == 3:
                pixel = pixel + (255, )
            dr = pixel[0] - self.previous_pixel[0]
            dg = pixel[1] - self.previous_pixel[1]
            db = pixel[2] - self.previous_pixel[2]

            if pixel == self.previous_pixel:
                # run
                self.run += 1
                if self.run > 61:
                    buffer[i] = QOI_OP_RUN | (self.run - 1)
                    self.run = 0
                    i += 1
                self._advance_pixel()
                continue

            if self.run:
                buffer[i] = QOI_OP_RUN | (self.run - 1)
                self.run = 0
                i += 1

            if pixel == self.cache[_pixel_hash(pixel)]:
                # index
                buffer[i] = QOI_OP_INDEX | _pixel_hash(pixel)
                i += 1

            elif (pixel[3] == self.previous_pixel[3]
                  and all((d + 2) % 256 < 4 for d in (dr, dg, db))):
                # diff
                buffer[i] = (QOI_OP_DIFF
                             | (dr + 2) % 256 << 4
                             | (dg + 2) % 256 << 2
                             | (db + 2) % 256)
                i += 1

            elif (pixel[3] == self.previous_pixel[3]
                  and (dg + 32) % 256 < 64
                  and (dr - dg + 8) % 256 < 16
                  and (db - dg + 8) % 256 < 16):
                # luma
                buffer[i] = QOI_OP_LUMA | (dg + 32) % 256
                buffer[i+1] = (dr - dg + 8) % 256 << 4 | (db - dg + 8) % 256
                i += 2

            elif pixel[3] == self.previous_pixel[3]:
                # rgb
                buffer[i:i+4] = (struct.pack('BBBB',
                                             QOI_OP_RGB,
                                             pixel[0],
                                             pixel[1],
                                             pixel[2]))
                i += 4

            else:
                # rgba
                buffer[i:i+5] = (struct.pack('BBBBB',
                                             QOI_OP_RGBA,
                                             pixel[0],
                                             pixel[1],
                                             pixel[2],
                                             pixel[3]))
                i += 5

            self.cache[_pixel_hash(pixel)] = pixel
            self.previous_pixel = pixel
            self._advance_pixel()

        if self.eof and self.run:
            buffer[i] = QOI_OP_RUN | (self.run - 1)
            i += 1

        return i, 1 if self.eof else 0, buffer

    def _advance_pixel(self):
        self.x += 1
        if self.x >= self.im.size[0]:
            self.y += 1
            self.x = 0
        self.eof = self.y >= self.im.size[1]

    def cleanup(self):
        del self.cache
        del self.previous_pixel
        del self.x
        del self.y
        del self.run
        del self.eof


def _save(im, fp, filename, save_all=False):
    if im.mode not in ['RGB', 'RGBA']:
        raise ValueError()
    fp.write(QOI_MAGIC)
    fp.write(struct.pack('>II', im.size[0], im.size[1]))
    fp.write(struct.pack('>B', 4 if im.mode == 'RGBA' else 3))
    if ('colorspace' in im.info
        and im.info['colorspace'] in [QOI_HEADER_LINEAR, QOI_HEADER_SRGB]):
        fp.write(struct.pack('B', im.info['colorspace']))
    else:
        fp.write(struct.pack('B', QOI_HEADER_SRGB))

    im.load()
    if not hasattr(im, "encoderconfig"):
        im.encoderconfig = ()
    bufsize = max(ImageFile.MAXBLOCK, im.size[0] * 4)
    fp.flush()
    encoder = Image._getencoder(im.mode, 'qoi', im.mode, im.encoderconfig)
    try:
        encoder.setimage(im.im, (0, 0) + im.size)
        while True:
            l, s, d = encoder.encode(bufsize)
            fp.write(d[:l])
            if s:
                break
        if s < 0:
            raise OSError(f"encoder error {s} when writing image file")
    finally:
        encoder.cleanup()
    if hasattr(fp, "flush"):
        fp.flush()

    fp.write(QOI_EOF_MARKER)


if '.qoi' not in Image.registered_extensions():
    Image.register_extension(QoiImageFile.format, '.qoi')
    Image.register_open(QoiImageFile.format, QoiImageFile, _accept)
    Image.register_decoder('qoi', QoiDecoder)
    Image.register_encoder('qoi', QoiEncoder)
    Image.register_save(QoiImageFile.format, _save)
```

Example use:

```py
from PIL import Image
import QoiImagePlugin


# open a .qoi image
im = Image.open('path/to/image.qoi')

# save a .qoi image
im.save('path/to/image', 'qoi')
```

Comment: Python is a slow language. You’d want to link the reference C code, rather than re-implement it in a slow language.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Of course it's not as fast as compiled code could be. One of my goal was to familiarize myself with working with binary data, hence the choice of the format which is specifically designed with simplicity in mind. Linking Python to the reference C implementation would also definitely teach me a lot, but it's a whole other exercise.